# Android: Actionbar

Tags: java, android, xml, tabs, android-layout

Can anybody help me...

I would like a actionbar above my tabinterface.. 
How can I implement an actionbar in my main xml..

I can't find any tutorial with a actionbar and tabinterface..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain a little more please? What exactly are you looking for? What are you trying to do with the action bar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Google IO Schedule App has source code for both action bars, and action bars with a tab interface below it.  http://code.google.com/p/iosched/

Comment: the action bar style code in iosched is awesome I use it all of the time.

Answer (score 15):

I have created a library, [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com), which is extended from the Android Compatibility Library to implement support for the native action bar all the way back to Android 1.6.

The key feature of this library is that it mimics the native action bar of Android 3.0+ and allows you to interact with it and theme it on all version of Android from 1.6 up through the current newest version, 3.1. There are samples and documentation on the website linked above which should give you a good idea about how it works.

You can also look on the [implementations page](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/wiki/Implementations) on the GitHub wiki for real world applications of the library.

[image]

Comment: How do I get this working ? Please share some implementation guide for this.... thanks...

Answer (score 8):

Here are two projects that offer actionbar implementations:

https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar

https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid